# Group column names and their values in two separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
      averageNumberOfOperationsPerPath  id   get  post  put  delete  
0                             1.285714           84  12.0   4.0  1.0     1.0   
1                             1.266667           84  13.0   4.0  1.0     1.0   
2                             1.266667           84  13.0   4.0  1.0     1.0   
3                             3.333333          124   3.0   1.0  2.0     1.0   
4                             3.333333          124   3.0   1.0  2.0     1.0
```

I need all the different columns get, post, put, delete and there are a  few more(I haven't mentioned here, the dataframe becomes too big for readability), under one column **methods** and other column **value** with their respective values.

Any help on how can I merge them to get the desired output while keeping the number of rows same.

Comment: please provide expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method:

```
df= (df
     .set_index(['averageNumberOfOperationsPerPath','api_spec_id'])
     .stack()
     .reset_index()
     .rename(columns={'level_2': 'methods', 0:'values'}))

print(df)

   averageNumberOfOperationsPerPath  api_spec_id methods  values
0                          1.285714           84     get    12.0
1                          1.285714           84    post     4.0
2                          1.285714           84     put     1.0
3                          1.285714           84  delete     1.0
4                          1.266667           84     get    13.0
```

Comment: Amazing solution. I will have to research how the code works though xD

Comment: This gives me an error unhashable type 'dict' at set_index statement.

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather may be one of your column is a dict?

Comment: I figured two of my columns have some values stored as dict, and i am not able to print out the unique values so i can delete them. Do you have any idea how can I rectify this error?